# The existence of solution for special equation on integer ring

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

I have a question which belongs to the field of number theory. Can we prove or disprove the following claim:

For all prime number $p=24t+1$ and the natural number $n=6t+1$, there is at least, one positive integer number $k$, such that the expression $\frac{k(n+1)}{7k-(n+1)}$ is a integer number.

I checked the above claim for prime numbers up to $17\times 10^9$, and the calculations verified it.

I will be so thankful for any helpful comments and answers.

Comment: What is the point to use simple numbers? Why can't we solve the equation for all numbers?

Comment: Just a comment: write $m=n+1$; then your conditions tell you that $4m-7$ is prime and that $m \equiv 2 \pmod{6}$. In particular, $m$ is not divisible by $7$. Hence the expression $\frac{km}{7k-m}$ is an integer if and only if $d := 7k-m \mid m^2$. In particular, if $m \equiv 3$, $5$ or $6$ mod $7$, then we can find such a $k$, namely by setting $d = 4$, $2$ or $1$, respectively.

Comment: @individ: When $n=7=6\cdot 1 + 1$, the given expression is never a positive integer. In this case, however, $24 \cdot 1 + 1 = 25$ is not prime. So this indicates that at least some restriction on the number $n$ is necessary (although it could of course be that the given condition is stronger than what is needed).

Comment: In view of @Tom's remark, this is hardly possible if $m/2=3t+1$ is a prime congruent to 1, 2 or 4 modulo 7: then $m^2$ does not have any positive divisor congruent to $-m$ modulo 7. And I would say there SHOULD be such $t$.

Comment: A counterexample: $t=14$, $p=337$, $n=85$. Thus $7k-86$ should divide $4\cdot 43^2$ which is impossible modulo 7.

Comment: @MeysamGhahramani: Well, you just modified your statement! $7\cdot 12-86$ is an integer but not a *positive* integer. If you allow negative integers, then it is indeed correct, as my argument above shows, since every $m$ not divisible by $7$ satisfies the fact that either $m \equiv 3$, $5$ or $6$ mod $7$ or $-m \equiv 3$,$5$ or $6$ mod $7$.

Comment: Meysam, it WAS a counterexample to your claim, since you asked the ratio to be a _positive_ integer. Now the claim is true, since one may apply the same scheme with taking $-4,-2,-1$ into account. But I wouldnt say that changing the question without any notification in such situation is a good way of doing things.

Comment: OK.I apologize,you are right.Thanks for your comments.